# Submit a form with jQuery / Javascript without ignoring "required" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, required

so I have the following form:

```
    <form action="register.php" method="post" id="register-form" name="register-form">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus="autofocus" required />
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn" onclick="$('#register-form').submit();">Register</a>
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;" />
    </form>
```

What I want to know, is there a way to make jQuery take care of the "required" tag when submitting a form? Right now it doesn't.

Comment: You can look for a form validation plugin; it's not a feature that's built in to jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger `click` on the submit button instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/PdUcq/

Comment: Works perfectly! One last question, is there any big difference between using `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn" onclick="$('#login-form-submit').trigger('click');">Login</a>` and `$("#register-form .btn").on('click', function () { $("#register-form-submit").trigger('click'); });` or why do I keep seeing the second one?

Comment: @JonasKaufmann not a big functional difference, but my method is a lot clearer/cleaner

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/#required),

required attribute works in most new browsers. In older browsers its not supported since its part of the HTML5 spec.

If you are looking for cross browser support with jquery you would have to use some plugin. One of the good ones is [this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Or you can go ahead and write your own custom validators, but why re-invent the wheel.